# Can't get IPython to start: "ImportError: cannot import name start_ipython"

Tags: command-line, python, ipython

I'm trying to start IPython from the terminal. I input:

`ipython`

into the terminal and I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 4, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
ImportError: cannot import name start_ipython
```

The weird thing is, sometimes IPython does work and I can get it to start, but I don't really know why it doesn't work sometimes.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

IPython from the default Ubuntu repositories does not install ipython to `/usr/local/bin/` so it looks like you have installed IPython in another way, and now it isn't starting properly. The easiest way to get things back to normal would be to uninstall IPython and then reinstall IPython from the Ubuntu repositories. You can find IPython in Ubuntu Software or reference it by its package name *ipython*.

By now IPython 2.x has become less useful, and it's time to consider installing IPython 3.x with the following command:

```
sudo apt install python3-ipython
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after an update. The problem was that there were two versions of ipython which were clashing, one was version 0.13.2 that I had installed using synaptic, and the other was version 3.1.0, which I had installed from the source.

In my `/usr/local/bin/ipython`, I had the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# This script was automatically generated by setup.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from IPython import start_ipython
    start_ipython()
```

From what I gathered from http://nullege.com/codes/search/IPython.start_ipython, it seems that start_ipython has been implemented in recent versions of ipython, but for some reason, when I was importing IPython in the python shell, it was version 0.13.2 which was being imported. This didn't have a start_ipython function, hence it raised an `ImportError`.

Now that I have removed the old version of ipython, the new version works fine.